# What's are the advantages of using CloudBees Core over Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I have tried Jenkins on my own and about to propose an enterprise grade CI/CD product to my development team which is around 40 people. CloudBees Core come at the top of my selected list since it is based on Jenkins and enterprise friendly as well.Apart from enterprise level support, I still can't really see the benefits to use CloudBees Core over Jenkins.

Is there anyone who used Cloudbees through your DevOps transformation journey ?

I would appreciate if you could discuss proprietary plugins and out of the box features that CloudBees Core provides.

Comment: As of 2023 when looking for a CI/CD system, have a very close look at what your source control system and/or issue tracker prefers.   You will appreciate in the long run if all this works well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer Jenkins over CloudBees as we have enough Jenkins knowledge in our engineering department. However, if their is a lack of such knowledge or interest then it could be useful to use a Software as a Service (SaaS) product like CloudBees. In general, this means that the department will be unburdened as the platform will scale automatically and the SaaS provider is responsible for keeping Jenkins up and running.

A downside of an Enterprise solution is that a fee is required. However, maintenance and in particular the number of resources that is required to apply it, is often underestimated in my opinion. Maintaining Jenkins by Engineers from the department means that they have less time to develop code. At the moment, getting a CloudBees subscription will not solve our problems as we are currently busy splitting the monolith.

Whether you should get a CloudBees membership really depends on your situation. Do you have a monolith? Has all code been untangled. Do you have microservices with clear boundaries or are they nanoservices? Long story short, do you have a robust architecture? If false, then CloudBees will also not be the holy grail.

While Googling, [another post on stackoverflow was found that could be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52527151/2777965):

> The first difference is support (as others have mentioned). CloudBees
> offers enterprise grade support as well as a fully vetted and tested
> version of Jenkins that will be more stable under various plugins and
> deployments. You can actually purchase "Support Only" from CloudBees
> if you are satisfied with your OSS Jenkins deployment and simply want
> support during upgrades, patching, break/fix, etc.
>
> From a feature perspective, CloudBees brings a lot from an enterprise
> manageability, scalability, and security standpoint.
>
> - Manageability: CloudBees comes with CJOC (CloudBees Jenkins Operations Center) built into the software. This is a single pane of
>   glass management console that allows organizations or large teams to
>   centrally manage the jenkins environment. Things like folders, RBAC,
>   pipeline and master templates, and the ability to rapidly spin up/tear
>   down a containerized jenkins master are all managed from this single
>   console.
> - Scaleability: CloudBees leverages Kubernetes to provide organizations with the ability to elastically scale Jenkins
>   environments as needed. With CloudBees, your oganization can move away
>   from a single "Monolithic"/"Frankenstein" master and into a
>   multi-master and distributed pipeline architecture. This greatly
>   reduces upgrade and administration complexity. This also eliminates
>   the risk from a single point of failure that a monolithic architecture
>   exposes.
> - Security: CloudBees allows organizations to install Role-Based Access Control within Jenkins. This keeps users from accidentally or
>   intentionally accessing repositories that they shouldn't be allowed to
>   interact with. CloudBees also provides "folders" to segregate specific
>   job executions onto specific agents. Lastly CloudBees allows
>   organizations to create pipeline templates and associated plugins for
>   each team. These templates can be as rigid or loose as desired per the
>   organizations security policies.
>
> CloudBees is regularly adding enhancements to further differentiate
> themselves from Jenkins Open Source and make themselves more appealing
> to large enterprise requirements.
>
> On top of the above, CloudBees has developed a presentation layer that
> rides on top of Jenkins for SDLC pipeline, CD monitoring, and metric
> tracking called DevOptics.